# Where can I get UnitedStates.gdb file

Tags: arcobjects, data

I am doing this tutorial 
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_geocode_a_single_address/00010000038r000000/

but it requires the following file: UnitedStates.gdb

I downloaded DataMaps10 from ESRI but I do not see any .gdb files.

Comment: This question is still valid, where to download UnitedStates.gdb used in the samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed that it would be in the same location as the downloaded maps from ESRI.

It's actually located here: 
C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\DeveloperKit10.0\Samples\data\Usa\USA.gdb

And gets installed when you install the VS2010 dev kit.

Too bad I can't create a GeoProcessor because when following this tutorial 
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Creating_an_address_locator/0001000004pm000000/
The call to

```
IGeoProcessorResult result = GP.Execute(createAddressLocator, null); //fails
```

Inspecting the messages  via GP.getMessages() yields

```
Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000039: Not enough reference data tables for this style.
Failed to execute (CreateAddressLocator).
```

After spending 100 years one the phone I've gotten the impression that in order to create an AddressLocator you just have to do the following

```
System.Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriLocation.LocatorManager"));
ILocatorManager2 locatorManager2 = obj as ILocatorManager2;
ILocatorWorkspace locatorWorkspace = locatorManager2.GetLocatorWorkspaceFromPath(@"Z:\ESRI\DataMaps10\streetmap_na");
Address - Dual Ranges");
locator = locatorWorkspace.GetLocator("Street_Addresses_US");
```

With this code locator appears to be a valid object, however, I have not yet got it to do anything useful, at least it didn't throw a COM exception.

Comment: I got the same problem yesterday when trying the sample against the USA layer in the arcgis sdk samples data.

Comment: nice to know I'm not crazy. :|

Comment: @iterationx, I will have look at data in a minute, I think the probelm is that our data doesen't have the right table and column names..

Comment: The data in the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\DeveloperKit10.0\Samples\data\Usa\USA.gdb don't have a US_Streets table. So I guess that why the geoprocessor is crashing on execute.

Comment: @MatthiasWestin Can you tell me what tool / process you used to determine that the table is missing?

Comment: @iterationx, I opened it in ArcEditor and looked at it in catalog pane.

Answer (score -1):

This is what you do

1) download the 3 ISO maps from the customer care site.  Make sure you decompress in the correct directory.

2) You need to modify the sample somewhat, here's what you do:

and replacing this code :

```
  IWorkspaceFactory2 workspaceFactory = obj as IWorkspaceFactory2; IWorkspace workspace = workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(@"C:\UnitedStates.gdb", 0); //THIS CAUSED ALL THE TROUBLE // 
    Get the Locator and QI to IAddressCandidates2 obj = 
    Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriLocation.LocatorManager"));
            ILocatorManager locatorManager = obj as ILocatorManager2; 
    ILocatorWorkspace locatorWorkspace = locatorManager.GetLocatorWorkspace (workspace); ILocator locator = locatorWorkspace.GetLocator("USLocator");



   With this code



    System.Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriLocation.LocatorManager"));
    ILocatorManager2 locatorManager2 = obj as ILocatorManager2; ILocatorWorkspace locatorWorkspace = locatorManager2.GetLocatorWorkspaceFromPath(@"Z:\ESRI\DataMaps10.doNotUse\streetmap_na\data");
    ILocator locator = locatorWorkspace.GetLocator("Street_Addresses_US");

//NOTICE : even tho the file name is Street_Addresses_US.loc, we *still* only open Street_Addresses_US
```

And ignore all that crap about creating a locator.

If you are reading this in the future and you find this helpful, I'd better get upvotes since it took me like 5 days to get this info. :)

Comment: -1 your actually not answering the question you asked.